# Attaching equipment, when the equipment wasn't actually cast

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Lets say, I use a [Genesis Wave](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGenesis%20Wave%5d), and I reveal an equipment. Can that equipment enter the battlefield 'automatically' attached to a creature already in play? Or does it just enter the battlefield, and I have to attach it by paying its equip cost during a main phase?

(Secondary clarification, is it true I can't put auras/equips on creatures also revealed by genesis wave?)

Answer (score 9):

Equipments *never* enter the battlefield attached to a creature unless an effect specifically says that it does, no matter whether you cast it or put it onto the battlefield with a card like Genesis Wave.

Aura Enchantments, on the other hand, *always* enter the battlefield attached to something. If you cast an Aura, it enters the battlefield attached to the object that was the target of the spell. If you put it directly onto the battlefield with a card like Genesis Wave, you choose at that time what object it attaches to. Just like casting an Aura, this choice is constrained by the "Enchant [something]" ability on the aura, so an aura with "Enchant Creature" can only be attached to a creature, whether or not it was cast.

One caveat you should keep in mind is that Genesis Wave puts all of the permanents onto the battlefield simultaneously, so you cannot attach an aura from among those permanents to another one of those permanents. This is different from a card like [Warp World](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWarp%20World%5d), which puts Enchantments onto the battlefield after other cards so that you can attach those Enchantments to other permanents that it puts onto the battlefield.

Comment: Technicality - Aura Enchantments always enter the battlefield enchanting something that they could legally enchant. An Aura with "Enchant land" will come in attached to a land, for example.

Comment: I added a bit to that paragraph to explain that.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. I added a paragraph about that.

Comment: alright thanks!
now i know that if i keep one mana open, and i reveal a 'swiftfoot boots' i can at least haste mana producing creatures that genesis wave revealed that turn.
thanks again!

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. You can click the checkmark next to the answer to "accept" it, which indicates that it answered your question/solved your problem.

Comment: A bit tangential so no need to add, but it's worth noting that when you cast an Aura you can't target permanents with Shroud (or Hexproof if your opponent controls them), but when the Aura enters due to Genesis Wave or for some other reason, those permanents are fair game.

Comment: "Equipments never enter the battlefield attached to a creature" Grifter's Blade does :)

Comment: I have never seen that card before. I added a caveat to that line.